# Vertical line inside td using a div

Tags: html, css

I have a table and in one of the columns I have some graphics. What I need is a vertical line 20px from left on top of all what is in the td element.

I tried something like this but the result is not good.

```
<td>
    <div>
        <!-- my vertical line -->
        <div style="width:20px; height:30px; z-index:1011; border-right: thin solid red;">
        </div>

        <!-- other content under the vertical line in td -->
        <!-- here width can be more than 20px -->
        <div style="width:5px; height:10px; z-index:1001; background-color:gray;"> </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

I have also tried with position: relative; for "main div" and absolute for other 2 but not a good result.

With this in place is perfect, I just need to add a vertical line on top of this 20 px from left

```
<td>
    <div>
       <div style="width:5px; height:10px; z-index:1011; background-color:gray;"> </div>
    </div>
</td>

 red line
--------|----------td-----

        |

--------|-- some line (one div in may case)

        |            

--------|---------</td>---

--------|---------<td>----

        |

---     |  other line

        |

------------------</td>---
```

Fiddle  [wrong result ("not good")](https://jsfiddle.net/j9z91s4o/)

this is what is expected

[image]

Comment: You need to clarify what it is that you're after (a diagram would help) and what exactly about your attempted solutions "is not good."

Comment: and please stop using inline styles

Comment: @AndréDion, by "is not good" I mean the it doesn't look good. The problem is simple inside a <td> a have a horizontal line (random length) and over that line I need a vertical line 20 px from left. I will make a diagram.

Comment: @TJ in project I am NOT using inline style but to keep the question simple..

Comment: @user2978984 I don't see how that makes the question any simpler, it just makes it more difficult. it'll much easier for us to play with the styles if you don' use inline styles.

Comment: @user2978984, The problem with "it doesn't look good" is that it's a subjective statement and isn't something anyone is going to be able to help you out with. Help us help you or be prepared to get down-voted or potentially have your question closed.

Comment: @AndréDion If you think you know to solve this can you wait a moment to show a diagram? Don't get angry because you don't understand what I say.

Comment: @AndréDion I have added a "diagram" so now do you understand what I need ?

Comment: Are you actually trying to create some kind of a bar chart using tables? Sounds like an XY Problem: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @Paul , yes this is exactly right. I mean I want to create a chart inside a table

Comment: Well, then you don't need to solve this question here but need to ask, how to create a nice bar chart using just HTML/CSS if you do not want to use one of the numerous charting libraries written in javascript, like D3.js for example.

Comment: @Paul Actually I problem is more complex then this. I am using a DevExpress GridView ( which in the end is a html table) and using js libraries is not a option

Comment: @Paul Actually my problem is more complex then this. I am using a DevExpress GridView ( which in the end is a html table) and using js libraries is not an option (it would take me a day to explain why) . So  my problem is this and I need to have a solution in css and html only.  Believe me if things would have been that simple I wouldn't ask ( I am not a rookie as one might think (not you) ). But thanks for your suggestion, it you seems to me that you are only one that understands my problem so far.

Comment: Still, adding a test page, Fiddle or a screenshot would massively help. Tables can be a mess to work with when you need to position elements.

Comment: @Paul I have added a sample, if you want and have time please take a look. Thanks!

Comment: @AndréDion if you still want to help me, now I think you have all the info you need. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are numerous pitfalls with a table used for creating a chart.

First, the table's cellspacing and the cells vertical padding must be set to zero to make the red line all the way from top to bottom. Second, the height should probably be set to some value, so the inner div of the last cells in a row can be set to 100% height in order to make the red line go from top to bottom within a cell (it also needs to be position absolutely due to possible overlap). Third, to make the horizontal lines appear in the middle of the cells, all cells should have a fixed line-height and the horizontal lines should be displayed as inline-block with vertical-align: middle.

```css
table tr td {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.horizontal-line{
    height:10px; 
    z-index:1001; 
    background-color:gray;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 5px;
    
}
.vertical-line{ 
  width:0px;
  z-index:10011; 
  border-right: thin solid red;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: 20px;
}

.width-5{
    width:5px;
}
.width-30{
    width:30px;
}
td, td > div {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>11</td>
  <td>
   <div>    
        <div class="vertical-line" ></div>
        <div class="horizontal-line width-5"></div>    
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>22</td>
  <td>
   <div>    
        <div class="vertical-line" ></div>
        <div class="horizontal-line width-30"></div>    
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Note: I also added and altered some other minor stuff like border-radius to reflect your screenshot a bit. If you want to play around, here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j9z91s4o/1/).

Comment: your solution is great. Thanks! For some reason in chrome ( not fiddle) the horizontal line is not in the middle vertically ( it is on top) I think vertical-align: middle; doesn't have effect. Do you have any idea about this. Thanks!

Comment: The horizontal line div should be displayed as inline-block and the line-height must be set, works for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I just made minor changes to your stylesheets and its working.

```
.horizontal-line{
    height:10px; 
    z-index:1001; 
    background-color:gray;
    margin-left: 5px;//addes this
}
.vertical-line{ 
  height:30px; 
  width:20px;
  z-index:10011; 
  border-right: thin solid red;
  position: absolute;//and this
}

.width-5{
    width:5px;
}
.width-30{
    width:30px;
}
```

Let me know if you are satisfied with this answer. :)

Comment: Yes it is ok, do you have an idea for vertical line to start from here the td starts on top. I mean it you want look the vertical line starts in first td from where the horizontal line starts. It is a bit of gap . Do you have an idea for this? But anyway your solution is good.

Comment: you mean like your diagram.

Comment: Yes to start were the td or table starts

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
<div style="width:5px; height:10px; z-index:1001; background-color:gray;padding-left: 20px"> </div>
```

or

```
<div style="width:5px; height:10px; z-index:1001; background-color:gray;margin-left: 20px"> </div>
```

Hope this'll help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution but my problem is not to have a 20px margin this is simple. Let me put it this way, if you draw a line 40 px horizontal then on that line at 20px draw another line over it only this time vertically. So you will have a line like this ---|--- where | is that red line.

Comment: "When you mean here width can be more than 20 px" then is it the lone in second <div> where width is 5px. Can you provide your full table structure.

Comment: Please that a look at added sample. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the red line exact in between(middle) of the gray line?

Comment: No it should not depend on gray line, just 20px from left. The red line is fix, the gray is generated.

Comment: Gray line can be 0 or 5 or 10 or 30 or .... any number. But the red it is always 20 px from left no matter what.